# PKCS#7 message constructed by our code, any weaknesses in the output?

Tags: encryption, digital-signature, smime

We have this as the PKCS#7 encrypted message. We would like to open this up for review and analysis here, for people to poke holes. This sample is generated via test certificates and keys. The concern isn't about the certificate info but that the encryption and signatures are alright. I'm not expecting cracking the crypto (!) - just ensuring no leakage of data from a privacy and authenticity of wrapped message.

In other words, *what information are you able to extract from just the message below?*

I'm putting the raw PEM format of the message as well as the `openssl asn1parse -in test.pem -i` output.

```
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----
```

***OpenSSL ASN1 parse output:***

```
    0:d=0  hl=4 l=1963 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=   9 prim:  OBJECT            :pkcs7-envelopedData
   15:d=1  hl=4 l=1948 cons:  cont [ 0 ]        
   19:d=2  hl=4 l=1944 cons:   SEQUENCE          
   23:d=3  hl=2 l=   1 prim:    INTEGER           :00
   26:d=3  hl=4 l= 415 cons:    SET               
   30:d=4  hl=4 l= 411 cons:     SEQUENCE          
   34:d=5  hl=2 l=   1 prim:      INTEGER           :00
   37:d=5  hl=3 l= 130 cons:      SEQUENCE          
   40:d=6  hl=2 l= 125 cons:       SEQUENCE          
   42:d=7  hl=2 l=  11 cons:        SET               
   44:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 cons:         SEQUENCE          
   46:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :countryName
   51:d=9  hl=2 l=   2 prim:          PRINTABLESTRING   :US
   55:d=7  hl=2 l=  11 cons:        SET               
   57:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 cons:         SEQUENCE          
   59:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :stateOrProvinceName
   64:d=9  hl=2 l=   2 prim:          UTF8STRING        :CA
   68:d=7  hl=2 l=  20 cons:        SET               
   70:d=8  hl=2 l=  18 cons:         SEQUENCE          
   72:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :localityName
   77:d=9  hl=2 l=  11 prim:          UTF8STRING        :Los Angeles
   90:d=7  hl=2 l=  26 cons:        SET               
   92:d=8  hl=2 l=  24 cons:         SEQUENCE          
   94:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :organizationName
   99:d=9  hl=2 l=  17 prim:          UTF8STRING        :Test Organization
  118:d=7  hl=2 l=  11 cons:        SET               
  120:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 cons:         SEQUENCE          
  122:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :organizationalUnitName
  127:d=9  hl=2 l=   2 prim:          UTF8STRING        :HQ
  131:d=7  hl=2 l=  34 cons:        SET               
  133:d=8  hl=2 l=  32 cons:         SEQUENCE          
  135:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :commonName
  140:d=9  hl=2 l=  25 prim:          UTF8STRING        :Test Organization Root CA
  167:d=6  hl=2 l=   1 prim:       INTEGER           :02
  170:d=5  hl=2 l=  13 cons:      SEQUENCE          
  172:d=6  hl=2 l=   9 prim:       OBJECT            :rsaesOaep
  183:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 cons:       SEQUENCE          
  185:d=5  hl=4 l= 256 prim:      OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]: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
  445:d=3  hl=4 l=1518 cons:    SEQUENCE          
  449:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim:     OBJECT            :pkcs7-data
  460:d=4  hl=2 l=  29 cons:     SEQUENCE          
  462:d=5  hl=2 l=   9 prim:      OBJECT            :aes-256-cbc
  473:d=5  hl=2 l=  16 prim:      OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:6A537AC9FE14255BFFEF3F88C779F2A1
  491:d=4  hl=4 l=1472 prim:     cont [ 0 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

One cannot tell whether an implementation of [CMS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652) (aka "PKCS#7) is secure by looking at the produced file; at best, one could spot *interoperability* issues.

I did not spot any interoperability issue right away; you use OAEP padding with RSA, which might be considered as bold (OAEP support is not completely widespread right now) but still conforms to the relevant standards (e.g. [PKCS#1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447)).

Security will depend *a lot* on the cryptographic algorithms implementations, in particular the [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) used to produce the random padding elements in RSA/OAEP encryption and the key for AES encryption. Nasty bugs can lurk there, and nobody could tell by just looking at one example PKCS#7.

I notice that this "Enveloped Data" object does not include the data itself, which is fine but requires the encrypted data to be transmitted or stored independently. Also, take note that **encryption** does not imply **integrity**; there are not many attack models where encryption is needed but integrity is irrelevant (in most situations, when the attacker can *observe* data, he can also *modify* data). To add checked integrity to this object, you would need to wrap it into a "Signed Data" object (and things become more complex because now senders also have a public/private key pair).